# Solve system of 2 integer equations

Tags: python, sympy

I have a set of two equations with three unknowns that has some conditions. `x`, `y` and `z` must all be larger than zero. How can I solve this? There is only one solution and I already know it, but I want to know how to get to it correctly.

These are the equations:

- `100 = x + y + z`
- `100 = 10x +2.5y + 0.5z`

Need to find `x`, `y` and `z`. They are integers and positive.

This is the code I have, but that does not work:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
eq1 = Eq(x + y + z, 100)
eq2 = Eq(x*10 + y*2.5 + z*0.5, 100)
#eq3 = x, y, z must all be larger than zero and integers
solution = solve((eq1,eq2), (x,y,z))
solution
```

Comment: You can add constraints (sympy calls them assumptions) when you create the Symbol, for example `x = Symbol("x", positive=True)` - have you tried that? Not sure about the integer constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem can be solved by [Z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), a [SAT/SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver:

```py
from z3 import Ints, solve

x, y, z = Ints('x y z')
sol = solve(x + y + z == 100, x * 100 + y * 25 + z * 5 == 1000, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0)
print(sol)
```

Output: `[z = 90, y = 6, x = 4]`.

Note that in general, Z3 only looks for one solution. To find subsequent solutions, a clause needs to be added to prohibit the already found solutions. (In this case there seems to be only one solution.)

Comment: Very cool! Didn't know z3, but this is so nice and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In sympy if you want to find integer solutions to equations then you should use `diophantine`. It doesn't handle systems of equations but you can put the solution from one equation into the other and call diophantine again:

```
In [69]: eq1 = x + y + z - 100

In [70]: eq2 = 10*x + 5*y/2 + z/2 - 100

In [71]: sol = diophantine(eq1, t, syms=[x, y, z])

In [72]: sol
Out[72]: {(t₀, t₀ + t₁, -2⋅t₀ - t₁ + 100)}

In [73]: [xt, yt, zt], = sol

In [74]: eq3 = eq2.subs({x:xt, y:yt, z:zt})

In [75]: eq3
Out[75]: 
23⋅t₀            
───── + 2⋅t₁ - 50
  2              

In [76]: t1, t2 = eq3.free_symbols

In [77]: [t1s, t2s], = diophantine(eq3, z, syms=[t1, t2])

In [78]: rep = {t1:t1s, t2:t2s}

In [79]: (xt.subs(rep), yt.subs(rep), zt.subs(rep))
Out[79]: (4⋅z₀ - 100, 500 - 19⋅z₀, 15⋅z₀ - 300)
```

The solution here is in terms of an integer parameter z0. This gives the set of solutions to the two equations but you also have the requirement that x, y, z are positive which constrains the possible values of z0:

```
In [80]: ineqs = [s.subs(rep) > 0 for s in [xt, yt, zt]]

In [81]: ineqs
Out[81]: [4⋅z₀ - 100 > 0, 500 - 19⋅z₀ > 0, 15⋅z₀ - 300 > 0]

In [82]: solve(ineqs)
Out[82]: 
               500
25 < z₀ ∧ z₀ < ───
                19

In [83]: 500/19
Out[83]: 26.31578947368421
```

We see that `z` needs to be `26` which gives a unique solution for `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
In [84]: z, = ineqs[0].free_symbols

In [85]: (xt.subs(rep).subs(z, 26), yt.subs(rep).subs(z, 26), zt.subs(rep).subs(z, 26))
Out[85]: (4, 6, 90)
```

Comment: Insanely complicated, but I tried your solution and is works. Thanks!

Comment: It's just complicated because `diophantine` doesn't handle multiple equations as inputs. Ideally most of the above would be handled inside `diophantine` but it hasn't been added yet.

Answer (score 1):

You did not explicitly state it but according to your comment x,y and z should be integers.
This complicates matters a bit.
This is now an example of a mixed integer programming (MIP) problem.
You could take a look at the following package for solving this in python:
[mip](https://pypi.org/project/mip/)

The downside of solving MIP's is that they are NP hard. But for this small example this should not matter.