# How to solve a Diophantine equation with 3 variables and 3 equations using SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

How does one add 3 variables and 3 equations using Python's SymPy? I tried using the documentation to SymPy, but it doesn't have any examples? One of the equations is to set a specific gcd.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the equations you want to solve. AFAIK SymPy is not solving systems of Diophantine equations.

Comment: eq1 = x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ==  x * y + y + z * x

eq2 = gcd(x,y,z) = 0

eq3 = x >= y >= z

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71108926/edit) your example and your best-effort code to your post.

Comment: See also [Solve system of 2 equations in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436610/solve-system-of-2-equations-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

SymPy cannot solve inhomogeneous ternary quadratic equations, so your equation must be transformed. So, your initial equation is

[image: x^2+y^2+z-xy-y-zx]

Let's introduce two new variables [image: u=y+z], and [image: v=y-z]. You can easily express the old variables as [image: y=(u+v)/2], and [image: z=(u-v)/2]. Substitution of these formulas into the original equation gives after simplification

[image: x^2+(u+v)^2/4-ux-v=0]

Multiply this equation by 4:

[image: 4x^2+(u+v)^2-4ux-4v=0]

Now, because [image: (2x-u)^2] we can write the equation as

[image]

Let's introduce new variables

[image]

[image]

Then

[image]

and our equation becomes

[image]

Finally, this can be written as

[image]

That means, that *a*, *b-2*, and *u-2* form a [Pythagorian triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). The general solution for these is well known:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now we need to return to our initial variables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the last equation we express *u*, substitute it to the first equation and use [image] to get the full solution in terms of initial variables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It must be noted, that due to the nature of the substitution which we made in order to solve the equation, not every possible combination of *p* and *q* will give a solution of the initial equation in integer numbers. We got some spurious non-integer solutions here. However, every integer solution of the initial equation can be obtained from these formulas with some values of *k*, *p*, and *q*.

We can easily check that these formulas indeed give a solution, by substitution these formulas into the original equation and simplification, for example on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%3Dk%2F2%28p%2Bq%29%5E2%2B1%2C%20y%3Dk%2F2%28p%5E2-q%5E2%29%2B1%2C%20z%3Dk%2F2%28p%5E2%2B3q%5E2%29%2B1%2C%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz-xy-y-zx):

[image]

Now, let's take into account the last set of inequalities: x>=y>=z. It's obvious, that in order for *y* to be larger or equal to *z*, the parameter *q* must be equal to zero. If we substitute *q=0* into expressions for *x*, *y*, and *z* we obtain the same result

[image]

It's obvious, that from this expression we can can get all integer numbers. Consequently, the only solution to your equation which satisfies the inequalities is *x = y = z* for all integer values.

Comment: So one can't add it in using sympy?